How to create a trusted certificate to run https in oracle 12c db
Need to run a https api in oracle 12c. oracle only supports utl.http request but what we have is an https api what are the solutions for this
tried creating wallet but cannot make it trusted. Please suggest ways to make certifcate trusted or suggest any other ways to run https in oracle suggest.
